# "This app can't run on your PC" is displayed when running a program

Tags: windows-8

I'm using Windows 8. When I try to use [SimpleAssemblyExplorer](http://code.google.com/p/simple-assembly-explorer/) Windows pops-up a message, and doesn't allow me to run that application. I tried to run it with the compatibility options; Windows 7 & XP, neither worked.

Since SAE projects seem to be inactive, there is no way to test the new version.

How can I get rid of this message and get the program to run?

The text reads "This app can't run on your PC. To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher."

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Windows 8 nag]

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the message in question. There isn't any reason this application should not work on Windows 8.  **This question has nothing to do with the modern user interface so I removed that tag.**

Comment: Well, I found the reason, that It seems, I have x64 app, which don't have any clue on the name. I downloaded x86 and it worked fine.

Comment: I think you should post your solution as an answer, and restore the screenshot in your question. This to help anyone else with a similar issue.

Comment: Ok; I'll do it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, the above error message (shown in the screenshot) is not very detailed. However, the problem is: using a different architecture than Operating System architecture. In my case, I wanted to (or tried to) launch the x64 executable whereas the OS is x86.

To solve the issue, I had to download the x86 version of the same software (the app), and that worked fine. The confusion arises because Windows 8 doesn't provide much detail for troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, as to help others that are looking for a solution.

Comment: I also had this happen when running a 64-bit program on a 32-bit machine. Gotta love 'em "friendly" messages which fail to tell you what actually went wrong.

Comment: Any particular reason I'd be getting this on an x64 system for what I thought was a 64-bit app?  (Maybe it's the old itanium 64 bit?)

Answer (score 39):

In my case, by mistake I had overwritten the exe file with  a 0KB file. And trying to run this caused the same exact message

Comment: The same in my case, except I haven't figured out what caused the zero byte file - was the output of a failed Visual Studio build attempt I suppose.

Comment: I ran a batch file that i copied from the command prompt, with the extra C:\....> at the beginning apparently this copies a new 0KB file over the existing one. This error message is the worst, should just say invalid exe or something.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, but with winhttpcertcfg.exe.

Comment: I was sure this didn't apply to me, but it made me look and sure enough this was it.

Comment: It's uncanny how many people this has happened to. There must be something somewhere that's causing this. A bad example in some documentation or something.

Comment: Have the same problem. What the hell is that? How is it possible?

Comment: Wow, thanks!  No idea why I fat fingered the file to 0kb.

Comment: Heavy FFS here (Fat finger syndome)! I have some idea how I might have done it. Was in Win10 console, wrote something, wanted to paste so right click -> paste (but hit mark all because of said FFS), was fast so right-clicked again and hit paste - except the second right click copyed all in console which then ran, and I guess something like must have executed that piped 0kb into my .exe.
Thanks for saving me so much headache with system restore etc.. :)

Answer (score 8):

Corrupted installer is another cause for this error message. See [Corrupted files are the cause of Windows 8 "This app can't run on your PC" error](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=722938).

Comment: That was the problem for me with Java 32 bit install. Thanks !

Comment: Same, the JDK 64 bit installer was corrupt.  Just had to download again.  This kind of thing makes you question your sanity.

Comment: My issue too. Try downloading with Internet Explorer. It allows you to resume download, whereas Firefox silently dropped the ball.

Answer (score 4):

A zero-length EXE file will also cause this error.

Comment: This was my case on Windows Server 2016. What a bizarre issue.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if anyone else has pointed it out. This might be also caused by you running a 16-bit executable file on a 64-bit OS. Like in my case here for an old software setup. You can usually get more info from the `Windows Event Log`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, compatibility settings usually fix that. For anyone in the future, if the problem still persists, there are a couple more reasons why the application might not launch. Heavy disk fragmentation, admin access, and malware can also be the causes. Defragmenting your disk and doing a scan with anti-virus software helped me solve an issue in the past. And yeah, as people mentioned, [architecture differences](https://ugetfix.com/ask/how-to-fix-this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-error/) can be a pain in Windows. Hopefully, this helps.