# Install Program on Windows 10 in Virtual Box

Tags: virtualbox, windows-10

*EDIT: The issue was actually Virtual Box related - it was not related to Windows 10 or the program I was trying to install.*

I have a machine running Linux Mint 17. On this machine, I have an activated version of Windows 10 running in Oracle VM VirtualBox.

I would like to install a program from a CD on Windows 10 that is running in VirtualBox.

When running the `setup.exe`, a popup appears:

```
This app can't run on your PC
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher.
```

Unfortunately, the vendor has not been helpful - stating only that "there have been no reported issues with installing the program on Windows 10".

I have tried running the `setup.exe` with administrator privileges and in all combinations of compatibility mode to no avail.

The installation CD has the following files:

```
Manual (folder)
Setup (folder)
Autorun (Setup information file)
CBase13 (Icon file)
Setup (Application file)
```

If I run the `setup_x64` Windows Installer Package file inside the `Setup`  directory, the following error appears:

```
This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.
```

Is there anything more I can try to do to get this program to work on Windows 10 inside a virtual machine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["This app can't run on your PC" is displayed when running a program](http://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program)

Comment: Have you tried turning Windows 7 compatibility mode on for the `setup.exe` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I did not select `passthrough` when adding the CD/DVD drive in the storage options.

The checkbox is located in my VM settings -> storage -> Host Drive DVD A (this will likely be different for different machine setups) -> Passthrough checkbox (tick this!)