# Windows 10 - "This app can't run on your PC"

Tags: windows-10

I'm getting this message when running my own software on Windows 10:

"This app can't run on your PC"
To find a version for your PC, check with the software publisher"

Are there logs for this somewhere so I can figure out what exactly is wrong?

It's a C++ application built on Windows 7 x64 (also tried x86) with OpenGL (some DX10 linked in there)

This isn't caused by the same thing as ["This app can't run on your PC" is displayed when running a program](https://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program) (x86/x64)

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the executable, then Compatiblity -> Run this program in compatibility mode for -> Windows 7?

Comment: "This isn't caused by the same thing as" - Except it is.  How you tell us the program in question?  Have you tried running it in a Windows 8.1 VM since you claim it is using DX10 which is odd.

Comment: Place the computer in Clean Boot state and check if the issue persists. This is to check if the issue is caused due to any third party program/app.