# Can't install gcc with cygwin on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, gcc

After installing cygwin on Windows 10, I tried to install gcc by

```
cd C:\cygwin
C:\cygwin\setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

as suggested here [How to Install the Latest GCC on Windows](http://preshing.com/20141108/how-to-install-the-latest-gcc-on-windows/).

But after executing the command I get this error:

> "This app can't run on your pc"

Has anyone else had this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: I have no problem  installing gcc within cygwin on my Windows 10 machine.  [This error mean something else entirely.](http://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program).  The file you are running at the command prompt is a Windows executable you do realize that right?

Comment: yeah of course...but i do it in windows cmd - so why not? I do execatly what is suggest at the link i posted.

Comment: The site doesn't work for me.

Comment: Works fine with MS Edge and Google Chrome.

Comment: Site does not work for me, I know the reason, but I simply can't reference it.  But I have compiled gcc within cygwin on Windows without any problems in the past.  Are you running a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Windows 10?  Based on the cause of the error, I am going to guess, your trying to run a 64-bit installer on a 32-bit version of Windows 10.

Comment: Are you running a 64 bit version of Windows?

Comment: Did you try installing it with the Cygwin Setup?

Comment: remove "-q" and see what is the real issue. Likely some MS security settings

Comment: @matzeri Even with `-q` the `cmd` shell contains a lot of output on what setup is doing ...

Comment: Have just tried following the installation guide linked to in your question, and hit the same "This app can't run on your pc"... Turns out that I'd forgotten to include a copy of the "setup-x86_64.exe" installation file (downloaded during the first step of Preshing on Programming's guide) in my newly created "C:\cygwin64" (or "C:\cygwin" in your case) directory. A little late to comment, but hope it helps!

Comment: @user69453 : For installing gcc, I have just invoked `setup-x86_64.exe` and then selected gcc manually. Does this also fail in installing you a working gcc?

Comment: @user69453 : For the safe side, I would also add ` --no-admin` to the setup options. I do this always, even on a PC where I have local admin rights, and if you install it only for yourself (and not for every other user of your PC), this should be fine.

Comment: Try installing it the NORMAL way(running setup-x86_64.exe without parameters).. Like some people have suggested. Then look at where it is and try running it. You could even use the 'file' command on it to get some info on the file.

Answer (score 0):

#### This app can't run on your PC

```
cd C:\cygwin
cd C:\cygwin\setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

The above command makes no sense. It shouldn't start with `cd` as you are already in the correct directory.

Try the following commands (which work here):

```
cd C:\cygwin
setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++ -P make -P diffutils -P libmpfr-devel -P libgmp-devel -P libmpc-devel
```

Note:

- This assumes you have a 64 bit version of Windows.
- If you have a 32 version of Windows you need to download the 32 bit version of Cygwin, which has a different installer.

> The most recent version of the Cygwin DLL is 2.5.0. Install it by running [setup-x86.exe](http://cygwin.org/setup-x86.exe) (32-bit installation) or [setup-x86_64.exe](http://cygwin.org/setup-x86_64.exe) (64-bit installation).

Source [This is the home of the Cygwin project](http://cygwin.org/)

Comment: The second ``cd`` was copy-paste error... I did it the way you described it, and I have a 64 Bit machine running 64 Bit Windows 10.

Comment: @user69453 Try installing from an Admin account.

Comment: I have cygwin 6.1 installed on my Windows 7 64 bit, it says gcc-core and gcc-g++ had download errors as can be seen in [this image](https://pasteboard.co/HqBJaS9.png). I suppose this is because my proxy server requires authentication. Where do I specify username and password for the proxy for cygwin setup? (Today only I installed python3 on cygwin and it did not gave any such error, so I was guessing what might have gone wrong, but I still feel its proxy authentication.)

Comment: @Mahesha999 See [Chapter 2. Setting Up Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html) "Connection Method - 
The Direct Connection method of downloading will directly connect. If your system is configured to use a proxy server or auto-configuration scripts, the Use System Proxy Settings method uses those settings. Alternatively, you can manually enter proxy settings into the Use HTTP/FTP Proxy section. "