# "This App Can't Run On Your PC" for specific user

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

We have a central server where EXE files are stored, which is accessible by a number of different users in the business. All EXEs have been generated the same way. However, for one of our users, when they attempt to run one of our EXEs (`my_exe.EXE`) they get a "This App Can't Run On Your PC".

However, an older version of the EXE (`my_exe_old.EXE`) that was generated works okay.

I've also noticed that when they view the EXEs from their own machine, the icon is different for the EXE that isn't working. The EXEs that work have this icon:

[image]

The EXE that doesn't work has this icon:

[image]

On my machine, when I view the central server, all EXEs have the former icon and work fine.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit:

They are generated from iExpress. Originally they are VBS files which just run some basic commands. Nothing really special about them. 64 bit.

I've tried renaming the file. Still works fine for me, but still doesn't work for the user. I'm guessing something's off with the user profile, and it's affecting this one particular file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I've edited my question now.

Comment: What can you tell us about the client machine? [This](https://superuser.com/questions/518289/this-app-cant-run-on-your-pc-is-displayed-when-running-a-program) seems relevant. You should [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: 16 GB RAM, 64-bit OS x64 based processor, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU @ 2.60GHz, Windows 10 Enterprise version 21H2 (OS build 19044.1889). Although most of the machines in the business are very similar.

Comment: Have you tried to delete the user's profile and have them log back into the machine?

Comment: @Ramhound Not yet. I wanted to make sure there wasn't a more specific fix before resetting the whole profile.

Comment: @TheDataPanda - I honestly strongly suggest just restoring the entire machine, if the user is getting the error in the linked question, it's a pretty generic error, ranging from executable associations, to the system running a 32-bit operating system trying to run a 64-bit binary, to simple security settings. Are you positive iExpress generates 64-bit executables, my research indicates, it's a tool from 2008 which was before Microsoft had a great deal of support for 64-bit OSs. It also seems it's connected to Internet Explorer, if all machines are NOT on the same exact version, I have 1 theory

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the suggestions. I'm not too familiar with iExpress (It's a just a legacy tool that was in place when I joined). Is there a more modern approach to generating EXEs?

Comment: @TheDataPanda, you mention **user** and **user profile** but is another user account on that same PC able to run it?